# Web SQL database folder

Tags: html, google-chrome, web-sql, offlineapps

I am using Chrome on Windows XP and just wondering what the folder contains the Web SQL database files?

I have used the Chrome Developer tool to examine the databases while I was still curious about that what is the location for storing these databases files.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I have already found the location:
C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\

Answer (score 1):

In Windows7:
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\